# Run multiple Angular app in One page

Tags: javascript, angular

Assuming there is already an existing angular running in the page. I would like to inject/add an isolated angular app into it (which runs in isolation with the existing angular app without interference).

For example, I would like to 1) insert a custom element say `<app-root-two></app-root-two>` in the page then 2) initialise/bootstrap that app (or vice versa).

How would I go about achieving this?

I know back in AngularJs it is possible because you can retrieve the DOM element and use `angular.boostrap(<dom-element>)` to initialise it but I don't think Angular has the same manual bootstrapping pattern. It is abstracted and it goes directly to DOM to find the root element, typically `<app-root>` in the page.

The current angular version I am working with is version 5.2 and Angular CLI 1.6.6. I have tried the `.angular-cli.json` file for generating multiple app however it targets two separate "index.html" files, that is two app in one project, not necessarily in one page.

Comment: How important is organic search indexing? I would use iframes within a main container app, with seperate views and subroutes for each of your apps.

Comment: @HunterFrazier search indexing not required. The second app is merely a "widget" alike which has its own states while able to access the DOM (which iframe cannot). Using the iframe approach also creates additional context that involves the need of domain/url. Think of the 2nd app as an isolated app contained in an async loaded third-party script.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. From your comment on the other answer to your question you said you don't have control of the existing app which is currently in another page. So if you didn't have control of it it would be better to use iframe, since you'll likely be bottlenecked by something else down the road without full access. What do you mean by 'do not have control' over the app? Have you considered setting up a proxy of some sorts, for the pieces you need or whatever https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: @HunterFrazier the 2nd app will be injected as content script javascript (chrome extension) on demand (whether user turn it on or not).

Comment: What you saying sounds interesting, can you provide more context? Take a look at this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wlenof?file=main.ts

Comment: Also take a look at this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16930 , it looks like team is considering this as a feature request

Comment: @mehany the example is in the direction iam looking for but not exact because in the example the context of app2 is not isolated from app1. I will have to run a few test to see if the manual bootstrap can be done like ng1 or not. I know in ng1 u can even bootstrap/initialise it and then add that bootstrapped element to the dom.

Comment: Yeah understood, Try to combine my answer with the demo I provided maybe you achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: having checked existing documentations for angular and it suggests having >1 apps in same page is not a good idea so will leave this question without correct answer. Unless angular has similar mechanism like jQuery.noConflict then perhaps it would be possible

Comment: @HunterFrazier Hello. Do you have a sample of your iFrame solution to load multiple Angular apps:? Thank you

Comment: Sorry Pascal I do not. I have implemented such features in the past, though, and it basically went like this. Use a proxy, (preferably at the server layer (Nginx) and not angular's built in route proxy aliasing or whatever it's called), to redirect a subdirectory location (e.g. /app2) to your secondary app (e.g. localhost:4201). This will allow you to serve the second app in a local, relatively addressed iframe (e.g. src="/app2") which will help with performance and cross-domain request issues. From there I suppose the possibilities are endless! I say, Iframes all day is the only way

Comment: Hello Charles. In my opinion, having multiple Angular apps on the same page is perfectly fine, as long as you're serving them up on seperate protocols using iframes. However, I don't have enough experience using them in a production environment to be sure! But for hacking they work wonders!

Comment: Upon some investigations, I ended up doing it in angular js. Please refer to my answer given below.

Answer (score 3):

You need a different root element on your second AppModule. Then simply import your second app scripts (runtime, styles, etc) but `delete window.webpackJsonp` first.

For example

```html
<app-one></app-one>
<app-two></app-two>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app-one/runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-one/es2015-polyfills.js" nomodule></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-one/polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-one/styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-one/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-one/main.js"></script>

<script>delete window.webpackJsonp</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app-two/runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-two/es2015-polyfills.js" nomodule></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-two/polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-two/styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-two/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-two/main.js"></script>
```

Though - to date - this works, the framework is clearly not designed for this. More complex apps with further chunking may have issues with the app's runtime that you're essentially changing when deleting webackJsonp object.

Polyfills that go to the global prototypes you may be able to skip reimporting.

Comment: Same can be achieved through the suggestion mentioned at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8902#issuecomment-458524290

Comment: Any latest update on this thread? Is Angular providing any way officially to support this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [overall-structural-guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#overall-structural-guidelines)

You can simply load one app but orchestrate ( lazy load ) many different modules that would behave as Apps. Each sub major module would have all the modules, services, components etc that it needs and it would be isolated.

Comment: Thanks @mehany. This solution indeed works however only when you have total control over the two apps. The solution I am seeking is say when you don't have control over the existing app which is already in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking into the source code, I had to do a bit of override. AngularJs does two things automatically: 1) bootstrap any "ng-app" 2) add a  tag. To prevent any conflict. I commented both bits out. Instead I took the content of  tag and placed it in my scss file and bootstrap my custom element manually

The other thing is Angularjs is loaded within the context of chrome extension content script therefore any window global defined directly in the content script will not bleed to the user page.

On top of that, I did use shadow dom to further isolate the application so that no css/js thing bleed in/out. As long as I don't modify any common aspects of the page I should be fine, e.g. location. Any global events binding I need to add/remove based on the lifecycle. The end result would look something like this:

```
<custom-element>
   #shadow-dom
      <!-- stylesheet if any -->
      <!-- js script if any -->
      <bootstrapped-angular-element>
```